# How to compile readline from source?

Tags: c, debian

When I compile readline into my directory /mypath as instructed (./configure --prefix=/mypath; make; make install) I get the following unresolved symbols in it:

```
ldd -r /mypath/lib/libreadline.so.6.2
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffffb186000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f450c62f000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f450cc07000)
undefined symbol: UP    (/mypath/lib/libreadline.so.6.2)
undefined symbol: PC    (/mypath/lib/libreadline.so.6.2)
undefined symbol: BC    (/mypath/lib/libreadline.so.6.2)
```

When I read the readme-file of readline, this seems to be a feature and not a bug:

```
`--with-curses'
    This tells readline that it can find the termcap library functions
    (tgetent, et al.) in the curses library, rather than a separate
    termcap library.  Readline uses the termcap functions, but does not
    link with the termcap or curses library itself, allowing applications
    which link with readline the to choose an appropriate library.
    This option tells readline to link the example programs with the
    curses library rather than libtermcap.
```

I tried it of course with --with-curses but that did not change anything, which is not surprising because it seems to be a setting that only affects some testing programs in readline.

My distribution (debian) however has a readline without undefined symbols, so it is clearly possible to do.

How to create a readline library without unresolved symbols?

Edit:

I have compiled and installed ncurses into the same directory and I have also tried to configure readline with CFLAGS=" -Wl,-rpath=/mypath" and --enable-static, without success.

Comment: I see you are using `;` to separate the `configure`, `make` and `make install` steps, did you check if those steps execute without any relevant errors? (maybe the `configure` step didn't find something, for example).

Comment: Yes, it compiles without error

Comment: This is off-topic here; a better place would be SuperUser or Unix & Linux. You should take a look at the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), with particular attention to the "Asking" section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those symbols are defined by libncurses, I think. You can probably confirm this like this:

```
env LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libncurses.so ldd -r /mypath/lib/libreadline.so.6.2
```

(I *think* `ldd` takes preloads into account when checking symbols, but it may not.)

The build script used by Arch Linux is [here](https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/tree/trunk/PKGBUILD?h=packages/readline). It looks like the trick is to use:

```
make SHLIB_LIBS=/mypath/libncurses.so
```

There's also some other adjustments to the `-rpath` options in a build file, so you might need that also.

Comment: Didn't work, but SHLIB_LIBS=/mypath/libncurses.so did! Please edit your answer so that I can award you the bounty - Thank you A LOT

Comment: OK, I'm not sure (without looking closer) why that would be the case, but .... Done.

Comment: Actually if you put /mypath into LD_LIBRARY_PATH, it will probably work, but that is not the case with my setup. Stackoverflow tells me I have to wait 21 hours to award the bounty...

Comment: Oh, right, if you don't have the library installed on the search path then `-l` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The `make install` step is installing the shared library in some directory, often `/usr/local/lib/`

You need to make the dynamic loader [ld.so(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) aware of that. I would suggest add *once* `/usr/local/lib/` into your `/etc/ld.so.conf` file then running `ldconfig` after each installation of new shared libraries inside it. See [ldconfig(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ldconfig.8.html), [ldd(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html)

You could also specify some `-Wl,-rpath` when linking programs with your version of `libreadline.so`

And when building a shared library you can link it to other shared libraries. On my Debian the system `libreadline` is linked to `libtinfo`:

```
% ldd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6
  linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffffccf3000)
  libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f45cffcc000)
  libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f45cfc23000)
  /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f45d046c000)
```

You may want to study the [source package](https://packages.debian.org/source/wheezy/readline6) of your `readline6`, since it contains the patches to the building procedure.

BTW, my Debian has a `libtinfo5` package (obtained with `dpkg -S /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5`)

Comment: That is a misunderstanding: I have no problem that readline is not found (it is found), the problem is that readline does have unresolved symbols inside, even though it complies fine

Comment: Comment on edit: Yes, mine is too (I also use debian), so how can I compile it that way?

Comment: I just searched around the web and libtinfo seems to be somehow part of ncurses - but of course nowhere can documentation be found how to build it or what it even is...

Comment: I want to compile everything from source, so the package does not do me much good. - I want to start at the official source (tarball) and create a working readline library